# PDF Export in ArcGIS Pro producing corrupt file?

Tags: arcgis-pro, pdf

When exporting an ArcGIS Pro layout containing PNG images (e.g. Logo, Photo or Chart), I cannot open the generated PDF file.

Export works fine without the image. It does also not work when using a TIFF or BMP image. *However, it does work using a JPEG file.*

When opening the PDF file, the following errors occur:

- A drawing error occurred.
- Insufficient data for an image.

[image: First dialog after opening PDF file]
[image: Second dialog after opening PDF file]

The error occurs with different images from different sources.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.2.4. Unfortunately, I do not have admin rights on this computer to upgrade to 2.3.

My current workaround is using a JPEG image with an acceptable resolution.

*Update 2019/04/13:* still looking for a solution to preserve vector data. I posted the question on GeoNet as well:

- https://community.esri.com/thread/231747-pdf-export-in-arcgis-pro-produces-a-corrupt-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does require **ArcGIS Pro 2.3**

There is an **Output  as Image** Option

[image]

**Option 2:** PDF Print Drivers

A non-upgrade approach is to have a pdf print driver installed

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There was an ArcGIS Pro 2.7 upgrade with a [BugFix](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/release-notes.htm) for **BUG-000132706** *Inserting a TIFF into a report or layout results in incorrect behavior on export* that mostly corrects this or a similar problem.

I can confirm that connectivity issues - slow or remote connection with otherwise acceptable lag - cause this problem to persist in some fashion (using ArcGIS Pro 2.7 here). Having data local, especially TIFFs, seems to help but a Layout with a Basemap as a service also causes this problem to persist for me.

@Mapperz's answer (both options) do not work in my case and increasing the quality of my Internet connection (from WiFI to Ethernet) was necessary.

Same or related issue: [ArcPro [sic] 2.6 Export PDF issue](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/arcpro-2-6-export-pdf-issue/td-p/263862)

In ArcGIS Pro projects where multiple Layouts are created from the same Map Frame(s) it seems doing a *Copy and Paste* of common elements between Layouts will cause errors writing to PDF but not to an image file (e.g. exporting to JPG).

Warning for those thinking of moving to ArcGIS Pro 2.7: You might want to wait for a Bug Fix [#000136364](https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDEzNjM2NA==) or use these Work Arounds [Exported Map Missing Lines Pro V2.7](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/exported-map-missing-lines-version-pro-v2-7/td-p/1011329)

In some ways it seems as if the PDF engine is still circa Adobe Acrobat 7.0 (i.e. the 2004 standard).